# Connect PHP via PDO to Google Cloud Storage MYSQL instance failure

Tags: mysql, pdo, google-cloud-platform

I created a database on Google Cloud platform to remove data storage from my server to google to allow moving of the application ext, I created an older version of data and created a PDO connection file in PHP to connect, but it will not.

**This issue is related to Google Cloud Storage, not Local mySQL server.**

```
PHP Error : Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'allfree'@'72.XX.33.XX' (using password: YES)
```

Using simple root / simple pass to test as SQL user / pass also fails

Google instance name : **afc-storage:us-west1:afc**

```
Google Error log : 2019-05-13 14:50:55.200 EDT
2019-05-13T18:50:55.199830Z 101583 [Note] Access denied for user 'allfree'@'72.XX.33.XX' (using password: YES)
```

Here is my connection code:

```
$dbhost = "34.83.119.218";
$dbuser = "allfree";
$dbpasswd = "XXXX";
$db_name= "allfreec_afc"; 

 $dsn = 'mysql:dbname='.$db_name.';host='.$dbhost;

try {
    $dbo = new PDO($dsn ,$dbuser, $dbpasswd);
    $dbo->exec("set names utf8");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

I am only using the database name "allfreec_afc", the instance is not required in the connection from what I keep reading over and over again.

Comment: Suggested answered question reffered to a localhost mySql server, that works great the connection to google cloud MySql is the issue here.

Comment: You should never use a root account to connect from PDO. Create another user for the purpose.

Comment: I used root just to test connection after tring user avvount, I set user account with IP of server so it errors with the correct username now but still access denied.  Very frustrating

Comment: I am at my wits end, made a user allfree using IP of my linux server, set password to 1234 and created the connection for PDO.  I get the same error, access for user allfree@ip using password:true failed.  I get the message on the google console as well so connection is there.  User name and password is correct??  I feel like I am missing somthing with the google cloud